8x2ram and 16x1ram difference
I want to know the difference between 8x2ram and 16x1ram and the storage capacity.
Is it correct that the total storage capacity is the same as 2^16 bits?
Is it correct that 8x2ram has 8 addresses and can handle 2 bits at once (2^2 = 4 in total)?
Is it correct that 16x1ram has 16 addresses and can handle 1 bits at once (2^1 = 2 in total)?
Is 8x2 ram better than 16x1 ram?
Please let me know if there are any more differences.

I don't think this is really a matter of computer science, but rather a matter of the specific technology you use.  The answer will probably depend on the particular motherboard, memory controller, and/or CPU you are using.

You give too little detail. total storage capacity of what exactly is the same as 2^16 bits? $2^2 = 4$ rings true - are these numbers relevant here, what should the $4$ signify with regard to the 8×2 RAM? better in what regard? One inportant parameter is cost. Maybe revisit How do I ask a Good Question?
